# Open or save a file after downloading in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, window

I have a use case where if file can be opened in new tab, it should be opened in new tab. If not, it gets saved with the given name(name should be the one set dynamically).

I have following snippet currently:

```
         if (windowService.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
             windowService.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, fileName);
         } else {
             const link: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement("a") as HTMLAnchorElement;
             link.href = windowService.URL.createObjectURL(file);
             if (fileName) {
                 link.download = fileName;
             }
             link.target = "_blank";
             document.body.appendChild(link);
             link.click();
             document.body.removeChild(link);
         }
```

When I use this, all the files are downloaded(including pdf/text which otherwise when tried with window.open() opens in a new tab). 
**My requirement is**: if files can be opened in new tab, they should be opened in a new tab(Ex. pdf/text etc(which open in a new when tried with window.open()).).
I understand that I can use **window.open()** but that doesn't support setting **desired name** to file.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Also how can I determine if file can be opened in new tab before downloading it? If I know file cannot be opened, in that case I download else I open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

The same requirement we solved using:

1. standard `<a/>` tags in the html of the client, to enable the browser to handle them in the standard way
2. changing the
   webservice so it returns the file with setting Content-Disposition
   header to `inline;`

Unfortunately, the attempts of tweaking `window.open` or `createObjectURL` to show proper name of the file... proved fruitless.

**Controller:**

Route: server/download/{guid}

```
var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(DispositionTypeNames.Inline);
contentDisposition.SetHttpFileName(document.Name);
Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = contentDisposition.ToString();
```

**component.html:**

```
<a [class]="'document-link'"
[href]="docUrl(document.id)"
target="_blank"
title="{{document.name}}">{{document.name}}
</a>
```

**Component.ts**

docUrl(id) function just constructs the proper url to the controller.

```
docUrl(guid:string){
  return this.fileService.url+'/download/'+guid;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To open file after download or save.

```
/**
 * Method is use to download file.
 * @param data - Array Buffer data
 * @param type - type of the document.
 */
downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type.toString() });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To force a download you need to set [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header in response header

Opening a file or download depends. e.g. to open PDF, If you have a PDF viewer supported in your browser it would open or else it would auto download

Comment: Yes, my browser does support opening a pdf but above code results in download of file instead of opening it a new tab. When i try window.ope(link.href), pdf is opened in new tab with random name.

Comment: @LotsOfQuestions yes, that won't have filename when opened. If you need that you have to make the url to serve directly from server with filename. eg. ~/sample.pdf that would open or download file with the name sample.pdf

Comment: Yes, but this fails my other scenario that if file cannot be opened in new tab, it should be saved with the name specified by function(Chrome assigns a random name).

Comment: @SanthoshS How can I send content disposition header if I am sending JSON response with other data like title, uploader name etc?